# Jquery vaildation plugin multiple error in one field using localization

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validation plugin and need to use localization for different language.
The original code would be like this

```
$('#form').validate({
rules: {
    'checkbox1[]': { required: true },
    'email': { required: true,
               email: true
              },
},
messages: {
    'checkbox1[]': "Please choose at least 3",
    email: {
             required:'Please input email',
             email: 'Please input valid email'
          }
}
});
```

If I use localization, my message_en.js would be:

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
     required: "Please choose your answer.",
     email: "Please input valid email.",
});
```

However, I shared the "required" message in email field. It means that if I didnt input email, the error message would become "Please choose your answer.". Obviously, it is not appropriate.

So, how can I separate the error message?

Comment: any reason u can not user a jQuery function for this??